# making a bot respond to an image using discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

New to bot coding using discord.py. As the title suggests, I'm hoping if someone can tell me how to make a bot respond to someone sending an image, whether it's pasted from the internet or uploaded from their computer.

Comment: So, for clarification, you want to detect an image given a message? I think listening to and responding to a message is out of the scope of the specific question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `.attachments`

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print(message.attachments)
```

For pictures from outside links you could do something like

```
  pic_ext = ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg']
  for ext in pic_ext:
    if message.content.endswith(ext):
      #do stuff
```

`.attachments` also returns a list with a dict inside

```
[{'width': 1200, 'url': 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/421005768494678016/486646740993179688/1200px-Greek_uc_Omega.svg.png', 'size': 27042, 'proxy_url': 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/421005768494678016/486646740993179688/1200px-Greek_uc_Omega.svg.png', 'id': '486646740993179688', 'height': 1200, 'filename': '1200px-Greek_uc_Omega.svg.png'}]
```

so to access any value (in this case its url) from it you can do something like

```
message.attachments[0]['url']
```

Example of dict code

```
  try:
    print(message.attachments[0]['url'])
  except IndexError:
    pass
```

Example of url code

```
pic_ext = ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg']
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  for ext in pic_ext:
    if message.content.endswith(ext):
      print("test")
```

Comment: so I tried this statement:                                                                                            
    if message.attachments[0]['url']:                                                                                good thing is that the program works and it detects that an image has been sent and replies with the message that I want. But it throws up this error:              line 67, in on_message
    if message.attachments[0]['url']:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yes, you can catch errors with try/except. I've added the example into my answer