# is there a way for a bot to wait for a certain reply?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot at the moment which should respond to either a right answer or wrong answer when the user inputs. my bot responds instantly after the question is sent (using discord.py) my code at the moment:

```
  ## code above working out answer and sending question
      if message.content.find(mainanswer):
                await message.channel.send("right")
            elif message.content != mainanswer:
                await message.channel.send("wrong")
```

Comment: Information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822769/discord-bot-waiting-for-message