# How can I make discord bot stop responding to any pictures?

Tags: python

I am new to python programming.

I recently made a discord bot that responds to specific messages on discord with strings from a list. However, anytime a picture is posted of any sort, the bot also responds. What can I write to make the bot return whenever a picture is sent?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # this is here to tell bot to stop a loop is the Hello message is from itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    msg = message.content

    if msg.lower().startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello {message.author}!')

    if any(word in msg.lower() for word in suspicious):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(sus_responses))

    if msg.lower().startswith('!8ball'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(eight_ball))

    if msg.lower().startswith('!ping'):
        await message.channel.send('Pong')

    if msg == 'MARCO':
        await message.channel.send('POLO...')


client.run(token)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173801/making-a-bot-respond-to-an-image-using-discord-py

Comment: Thank you! I found this earlier and tried it and it didn't work for whatever reason, but when i tried it this time, it worked!